# No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1) trying to send a Delete with body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have the following code because I have to send a DELETE request with body.

```
import retrofit2.http.HTTP;
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "userMailbox", hasBody = true)
Call<ResponseBaja> baja(BodyBaja body);
```

But I always get `No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add @Body annotation

```
Call<ResponseBaja> baja(@Body BodyBaja body);
                       ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Damn, I feel dumb.